# I can't grep some inputrc string

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression, quoting, string

`bind -p |grep -E "\\e.\":"` work

but

`bind -p |grep -E "\\e\\C-.\":"` don't work

I tried a lot of combination

Comment: In the future, please include a sample of the data you are trying to match (as if in the file) and yourr expected output from your command. (I didn't downvote, but I think that is likely why you have downvotes).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, I'll give more details for the next question

Comment: @user3634569 Note that you are also able to edit _this_ question to improve it, would you wish to do so.  Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a double-quoted string for the regular expression, you have to add one extra backslash to escape the escaping of each literal backslash that you want to match. This is because the shell will interpret backslashes in double-quoted strings.

```bash
bind -p | grep "\\\e.\":"
bind -p | grep "\\\e\\\C-.\":"
```

(Note that `-E` is not needed as your regular expression is not an extended regular expression.)

Alternatively, and I would suggest you do this instead, use single quotes:

```bash
bind -p | grep '\\e.":'
bind -p | grep '\\e\\C-.":'
```

---

The shell would interpret your original command line argument `"\\e\\C-.\":"` as `\e\C-.":`, which, as a regular expression, is the same as `eC.-":`.

Your original expression string `"\\e.\":"` "works" because it corresponds to the regular expression `e.":`.  It however does not try to match the literal backslash before the `e`.

---

Alternative formulation of the expressions using `[\]` instead of `\\`:

```bash
bind -p | grep '[\]e.":'
bind -p | grep '[\]e[\]C-.":'
```

Or, if you just want to grep for the literal string `\e\C-`, use `grep` with `-F` to make it use the pattern as a "fixed string" as opposed to a regular expression:

```bash
bind -p | grep -F '\e\C-'
```